# Checking all of facts in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a number of facts that represents a cell with a row,Column and the number in that certain cell, And I want to check those facts just like checking  a normal array .

I tried this function but it doesn't seem to work ,I don't think I am checking all my facts.

```
allcolored(X,Y) :-
   cell(X,Y,_),
   X1 is X - 1,
   Y1 is Y - 1,
   allcolored(X1,Y1).
```

Comment: If the cells are already provided in the form `cell(X,Y,Value).`, why don't you just query for the desired row and column? For example: if your facts include `cell(2,2,120).`, you can ask _What is the value of the cell at row=2 and column=2?_ by querying `?- cell(2,2,Value).` to which Prolog will respond by answering `Value = 120`. Then you might want to ask _Are there any more solutions?_ by hitting the __;__-key: `Value = 120 ;` and, given you have only one fact for row=2 and column=2, Prolog will tell you that there aren't any: `false.`

Comment: I don't see any information in your predicate that represents what it means for a cell to be "colored". `_` is an "anonymous" variable and using it means you don't care what the value is.

Comment: yes i don't want the number in the cell i just want to know if the whole fact exists because its a dynamic facts which i assert and just want to check that all of them are asserted

Comment: If you query for a pair of X/Y-values you don't have a corresponding fact for, Prolog will answer `false`. That's how you know. But since I clearly don't get the point of your question, I politely ask you to clue me in by providing a few example facts and a few example queries that illustrate what behaviour you expect from `allcolored/2`.

Comment: ok so its like grid of cells which have a diminsion  of x & y where each cell is a fact that is maybe asserted or not and i want to check on each cell for the existing of that fact ,exmaple : if i send `allcolored(5,5)` i want it to check for the facts in a 5X5 grid

Comment: About Prolog predicate behavior...Your predicate `allcolored(X,Y) :-
   cell(X,Y,_), ..., allcolord(X1, Y1).`  fails for two reasons. First, you do not have a base case, so there's no condition to end recursion. Secondly, on the recursive call, the new query to `cell(X, Y, _)` starts over at the beginning of the asserted facts. So the new `cell(X, Y, _)` call will continue to find the first `cell/3` fact and succeed on each recursive call. You may need to use `findall/3` then process a list of cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if, given a pair of X/Y coordinates, all positions in the grid spanned by those coordinates are covered by `cell/3` facts. For arguments sake, let's consider that the following facts are currently present:

```
cell(1,1,100).
cell(1,2,200).
cell(1,3,300).
cell(2,1,110).
cell(2,2,120).
cell(2,3,130).
```

Looking at your attempt for a recursive rule, you *try* to check if, for a given pair, say 2/2, there are facts `cell/3` for the pairs 2/2 and 1/1. But you probably *want* to check if the following pairs are covered: 2/2, 1/2, 2/1 and 1/1. As you can see in this sequence, the X-coordinate is being reduced to 1, then the Y-coordinate is decreased while the X-coordinate starts over at 2 again. So you need to preserve the original value of X somehow. This can be done with an auxiliary predicate with an additional argument. Your predicate `allcolored/2` would then be the calling predicate for such a predicate, let's call it `allcolored_/3`:

```
allcolored(X,Y) :-
   allcolored_(X,Y,X).
```

As @lurker already pointed out, your predicate is lacking a base case, where the recursion can stop. An obvious candidate for that would be the pair 1/1:

```
allcolored_(1,1,_) :-
   cell(1,1,_).
```

Then a rule is needed to describe that all values between X and 2 have to be covered by `cell/3`:

```
allcolored_(X,Y,Max) :-
   cell(X,Y,_),
   X > 1,
   Y >= 1,
   X0 is X-1,
   allcolored_(X0,Y,Max).
```

And an additional rule to describe the change to the next lower Y-coordinate, once X reached 1:

```
allcolored_(1,Y,Max) :-
   cell(1,Y,_),
   Y > 1,
   Y0 is Y-1,
   allcolored_(Max,Y0,Max).
```

Now you can test if a grid, spanned by the coordinates you provide, is covered by facts `cell/3`:

```
?- allcolored(2,2).
true ;
false.

?- allcolored(2,3).
true ;
false.

?- allcolored(3,3).
false.
```

Note that the above code assumes that the smallest coordinate in the grid is 1. To change that, to e.g. 0, you have to replace the 1's in the goals `X >1`, `Y >= 1` and `Y > 1` by 0's. Also note that due to the ordering of the goals (the `cell/3` goals first) you can also ask questions like *What grids are there that are covered by the facts of `cell/3`?* :

```
?- allcolored(X,Y).
X = Y, Y = 1 ;
X = 2,
Y = 1 ;
X = Y, Y = 2 ;
X = 2,
Y = 3 ;
X = 1,
Y = 2 ;
X = 1,
Y = 3 ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for the existence of a fact for *every* pair of indices in range, check for the non-existence of non-existence of the fact for *some* pair of indices in range:

```
allcolored(X,Y) :- 
    \+ (between(1,X,A), between(1,Y,B), \+ cell(A,B,_)).
```

this says: `allcolored(X,Y)` holds if there are no indices `A, B` in allowed ranges (`1..X`, `1..Y`) for which the fact `cell(A,B)` doesn't exist.

In other words, *"there are no empty cells in the given area"* is the same thing as *"all cells in the given area are full"*.